# I draw image to form, but it is limited to top left corner of form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, graphics, drawing

I have created a form and imported two square images saved as PNG files in resources. when I run the code below the black box which is drawn will only go about 200 pixels in the x coordinate and 150 pixels in the Y coordinate from where the image is drawn, after that the background remains white, and it seems I am unable to draw anything and anything I do draw stops around this point.

I have tried redrawing the image in a completely different location on the screen and It will not be visible if it is not within the region to the top left of the form, I have also tried drawing other images, but they also cease to exist when not in the top left of my form.

What I want is for the black box/other images to be drawn across the whole form, and not just in the top left corner, which something is preventing me from doing.

```
Public Class Form1
   Dim gameGraphics As System.Drawing.Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics

   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       'Draws black square which I have saved as resource 
       gameGraphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.black_Background, 0, 80, 1600, 600)
       'Draws green square which I have saved as resource 
       gameGraphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.greenSquare, 2, 82, 40, 40)
   End Sub

   'makes the form fullscreen
   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
       Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
   End Sub


   'closes form if quitbutton is clicked
   Private Sub QuitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles QuitButton.Click
       Me.Close()
   End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Delete this: `Dim gameGraphics As System.Drawing.Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics`.  Use the paint event to get your graphic object.  Don't set window properties in the load event.  Do it in the designer or the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Graphics Object cannot be stored. It's Erased/Updated constantly. You'll end up with an invalid one. It's really useless and, you could say, a mistake.
You can use a Graphics Object created with `Control.CreateGraphics()`, but you have to remember that it's not *persistent*; it will be erased when the Control you have painted it on needs to re-Paint() itself (e.g. you drag something over it, if it's a Form, when it's minimized etc.).

Those Properties, `Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None` and `Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized` are better set in the designer.
 There's no reason to set them on a `Form.Load()` event. Their state is not even subject to a condition.
 In general, leave the Load event of a Form as lightweight as possible and avoid setting properties that can cause cascading events.

An example:

Define an object to store your images:
(The `DrawBitmaps` flag is used to let your Form know when to draw those Bitmaps).

```
Public Class MyBitmap
    Public Property Image As Bitmap
    Public Property Position As Point
    Public Property Size As Size
End Class

Public MyBitmaps As List(Of MyBitmap)
Public DrawBitmaps As Boolean = False
```

Somewhere (even in `Form.Load()`), fill the list with you bitmaps:
(Here, the bitmap size is set to original size, but you can set it to whatever dimension you see fit).

```
MyBitmaps = New List(Of MyBitmap)
MyBitmaps.Add(New MyBitmap With {.Image = My.Resources.black_Background,
                                 .Position = New Point(0, 80),
                                 .Size = New Size(My.Resources.black_Background.Width,
                                                  My.Resources.black_Background.Height)})
MyBitmaps.Add(New MyBitmap With {.Image = My.Resources.greenSquare,
                                 .Position = New Point(2, 82),
                                 .Size = New Size(My.Resources.greenSquare.Width,
                                                  My.Resources.greenSquare.Height)})
```

The Paint() event `e.Graphics` of the Form performs all the painting:
(Note that it will not paint its surface unless the `DrawBitmaps` flag is set to `True` => It will not paint those Bitmaps when it's loading/showing. The other condition is a basic fail-safe.

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
    If DrawBitmaps = True AndAlso MyBitmaps.Count > 0 Then
        For Each _Item As MyBitmap In MyBitmaps
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(_Item.Image, New Rectangle(_Item.Position, _Item.Size))
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

When `Button1` is clicked, the Form will draw your list of Bitmaps:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    DrawBitmaps = True
    Me.Invalidate()
End Sub
```

Somewhere in your code, add a new Bitmap and tell the Form to Invalidate only a region of the size of this new Bitmap:

```
MyBitmaps.Add(New MyBitmap With {.Image = My.Resources.[AnotherBitmap],
                                 .Position = New Point(50, 50),
                                 .Size = New Size(200, 200)})

Me.Invalidate(New Rectangle(MyBitmaps.Last().Position, MyBitmaps.Last().Size))
```

Remove a Bitmap from the list and repaint:

```
MyBitmaps.RemoveAt(0)
Me.Invalidate()
```